# No model objects defined when generating python-flask server stub

Tags: swagger-codegen, openapi

*Update: I discovered the issue. My use of the term "File" for an object in definitions appeared to be causing this issue. I renamed the object to "FileThing" as a test and swagger-codegen generated the expected model object and module. (Perhaps this is related to https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/3223 ?).*

When using swagger-codegen to generate a Python Flask (Connexion) server stub from an OpenAPI v2 specification, I do not see any model objects in the resulting source code. However, other language/API targets such as go-server do generate model objects. I am using swagger-codegen-cli-2.3.1.jar. My specification is very simple at this point and is:

```
swagger: "2.0"

info:
  version: 0.0.1
  title: Blah API
  description: An API for interacting with the blah system

paths:

  /files:

    get:
      description: Retrieves information on files that match the specified criteria

      produces:
      - "application/json"

      parameters:
        - name: tags
          type: array
          description: The tags for which matching files are to be returned
          in: query
          items:
            type: string

      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful response
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: "#/definitions/File"

definitions:
  File:
    type: object
    properties:
      file_id:
        type: "string"
        format: "uuid"
      path:
        type: "string"
      tags:
        type: array
        items:
          type: "string"
```

As you can see, I would expect to see a model object created for the File object defined in the definitions section. However, the models package under Source/swagger_server only contains a base_model.py module with no additional definition beyond the base model class itself. I run swagger-codegen-cli as follows:

```
sknick@sknick:~/Repo/Blah/Server$ java -jar /home/sknick/Misc/swagger-codegen-cli-2.3.1.jar generate -l python-flask -o ./Source -i ./api.yaml
[main] INFO io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser - reading from ./api.yaml
[main] WARN io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Empty operationId found for path: GET /files. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: filesGET
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator - Model File not imported due to import mapping
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /home/sknick/Repo/Blah/Server/./Source/swagger_server/controllers/default_controller.py
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator - File exists. Skipped overwriting /home/sknick/Repo/Blah/Server/./Source/swagger_server/test/test_default_controller.py
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /home/sknick/Repo/Blah/Server/./Source/README.md
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /home/sknick/Repo/Blah/Server/./Source/setup.py
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /home/sknick/Repo/Blah/Server/./Source/tox.ini
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /home/sknick/Repo/Blah/Server/./Source/test-requirements.txt
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /home/sknick/Repo/Blah/Server/./Source/requirements.txt
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /home/sknick/Repo/Blah/Server/./Source/git_push.sh
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /home/sknick/Repo/Blah/Server/./Source/.gitignore
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /home/sknick/Repo/Blah/Server/./Source/.travis.yml
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /home/sknick/Repo/Blah/Server/./Source/Dockerfile
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /home/sknick/Repo/Blah/Server/./Source/.dockerignore
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /home/sknick/Repo/Blah/Server/./Source/swagger_server/__init__.py
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /home/sknick/Repo/Blah/Server/./Source/swagger_server/__main__.py
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /home/sknick/Repo/Blah/Server/./Source/swagger_server/encoder.py
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /home/sknick/Repo/Blah/Server/./Source/swagger_server/util.py
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /home/sknick/Repo/Blah/Server/./Source/swagger_server/controllers/__init__.py
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /home/sknick/Repo/Blah/Server/./Source/swagger_server/models/__init__.py
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /home/sknick/Repo/Blah/Server/./Source/swagger_server/models/base_model_.py
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /home/sknick/Repo/Blah/Server/./Source/swagger_server/test/__init__.py
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /home/sknick/Repo/Blah/Server/./Source/swagger_server/swagger/swagger.yaml
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /home/sknick/Repo/Blah/Server/./Source/.swagger-codegen/VERSION
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "don't see ... model objects created in the generated code"? I've just generated python-flask for Petstore, and the models are there in the swagger-server\models dir. Can you post your OpenAPI spec, the actual results and expected results? Which version of Swagger Codegen are you using?

Comment: I revised my question. Thanks for the feedback so far.

Comment: I noticed too that in place of the import of the File from the Python module that it was doing import java.io.File, so there is some sort of a bug in the tool.

Comment: Reported possible new bug: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/8134

Comment: Re: update - yes, issue #3223 looks like the same thing. It was probably fixed for some generators but not for python-flask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug in the python-flask generator where it does not generate models that match certain Java class names, such as `File`, `Date`, `Set`, etc. The "ignore model" behavior is configured in the `DefaultCodegen` class via `importMapping` here:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/DefaultCodegen.java#L835

Some generators, such as C#, clear the `importMapping` because they don't use Java class mappings:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/languages/AbstractCSharpCodegen.java#L56

```
importMapping.clear();
```

but python-flask generator does not do this. It should probably clear `importMapping` as well, but I'm not a Python/Flask dev so I'm not sure.

I suggest that you [open an issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues) in the Swagger Codegen repository, and/or submit a PR.

In the meantime, some possible workarounds are:

- Rename the model, e.g. to `FileDTO`.
- [Create a custom generator](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#making-your-own-codegen-modules) based on python-flask, add `importMapping.clear()`, and use your custom generator.